# Path in Magento gets wrong when uploaded to webbserver

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

So I have been developing a e-commerce page locally using Xampp with Magento, it has been going fine until I tested the page on a hosting-site. Something with the paths is wrong.

For example, locally when going to a page it's
**localhost/exampleRootDirForMagento/ExampleProductCatagory**

But when using a hosting service and I try
     **example.com/ExampleCatagoryProduct**
I get an 500 Internal Server Error. But however if i try
     **example.com/index.php/ExampleCatagoryProduct**
on the hosting service the page loads. But then all the links on the page is wrong.

So in some magically way when I uploaded it to the hosting service the path needs a index.php before entering the the product category. I haven't found anything on this matter so if anyone has any ideas of how this index.php appeared and how to get rid of it, i would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because Apache rewrite failed. You have to upload .htaccess (get original from magento package or upload one from your localhost) file in your hosting, in magento root directory.

Comment: Thank you! Was not just entirely replacing them though, needed some tweaking but you got me on the right track!